# VLOOKUP issue in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following basic VLOOKUP setup, having not used Excel in anger for a while. I am looking up the values a, b and C in a table containing two columns.

```
                                                    <value returned>     <expected>

a       1   b       =VLOOKUP(A1,C$1:D$1,1,FALSE)    #N/A                 #N/A
b       2   c       =VLOOKUP(A2,C$2:D$2,1,FALSE)    #N/A                 2
c       3   d       =VLOOKUP(A3,C$3:D$3,1,FALSE)    #N/A                 3
```

I am getting #N/A returned for all rows (as shown to the right), but I would expect the values to the right again to be returned. Can someone please explain what I have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: vlookup expects the lookup to be on the left not the right, therefor use INDEX/MATCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still stick to dataset :

```
a       1   b      
b       2   c      
c       3   d
```

then : `=INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$3,0))`

So if you re-arrange the data as :

```
a       2   b      
b       3   c      
c       4   d
```

then use : `=INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$3,0))`

hope that helps. (:

Answer (score 1):

When using `VLOOKUP`, the column containing the key to be matched has to be the first column on the left of the range.  So change your data layout to this:

```
A   B   C   D
a       b   1
b       c   2
c       d   3
```

and use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, C$1:D$3, 2, FALSE)
```

and then it should work.  As @Scott mentioned in his comment, if you want to keep your data layout the same, you could look into using `INDEX`.